# Распарсить xml поместив дочерние элементы в переменную golang

Tags: xml, golang

Нужно распарсить большой xml файл вытащив из него html и картинку
пример:

```
<node>
  ...
  <descreption>
  тут распологается текст <b> разный </b>
  <p> который нужно в переменную записать</p>
  </descreption>
  ...
<node/>
```

делаю по примеру из документации

```
var data List
xmlFile, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
xml.Unmarshal(xmlFile, &data)
```

структуры

```
type List struct{
  XMLName xml.Name `xml:"node" json:"-"`
  Descreption string `xml:"descreption,innerxml" json:"descreption"` 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type Descreption struct{
  Descreption string `xml:",innerxml"`
}

type List struct{
 XMLName xml.Name `xml:"node" json:"-"`
 Descreption Descreption `xml:"descreption" json:"descreption"` 
}
```